How to test if a file may be an archive on Linux
Context
I want to (try) unpack an MSI, Zip (or any archive), or EXE to inspect the contents.
I also want to recursively try unpack all extracted files.
Using 7zip, I have found I can unpack MSI, Zip, EXE and it just fails if it can't treat the file like an archive. This is good enough for me.
However, running 7z over every file is too slow. I want to quickly skip files which don't look like they're compressed.
I have read this: Determine whether a particular file is compressed

Note: in contrast to comment here I actually would like to unpack anything that could be an archive (like an ODF document or EPUB)

This is what I have so far. It is correct, but inefficient (my script COMPRESSED=/home/wineuser/bin/compressed always returns true):
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
COMPRESSED=/home/wineuser/bin/compressed

# Initial archive and output directory
initial_archive=$1
output_dir=$2

# Function to extract an archive
extract_archive() {
    local archive=$1
    local output_dir=$2

    # Extract the archive to the output directory
    7z x "$archive" -o"$output_dir" -y || return
    
    # Find all files in the output directory
    idx=0
    find "$output_dir" -type f -exec "$COMPRESSED" {} \; -print | while read line; do
        idx=$((idx+1))
        extract_archive "$line" "$output_dir"/"$idx" || true
    done
}

# Extract the initial archive recursively
extract_archive "$initial_archive" "$output_dir"

Requirements
I want this to work in general, so thinking something like:
if (file "$f" | grep -q compressed ) ; then
     # try uncompress with 7zip
fi

BUT, file doesn't have the word "compressed" anywhere for MSI. Neither does file -k.
Example output for MSI:
Composite Document File V2 Document, Little Endian, Os: Windows, Version 6.2, MSI Installer, Code page: 1252, Title: Installation Database, Subject: DB Browser for SQLite, Author: DB Browser for SQLite Team, Keywords: Installer, Comments: This installer database contains the logic and data required to install DB Browser for SQLite., Template: x64;1033, Revision Number: {E6668432-CAB0-416D-9422-E24C9E71DB68}, Create Time/Date: Sun May  2 16:30:00 2021, Last Saved Time/Date: Sun May  2 16:30:00 2021, Number of Pages: 405, Number of Words: 2, Name of Creating Application: Windows Installer XML Toolset (3.11.1.2318), Security: 2

Example output for self-extracting exe:
PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows, Nullsoft Installer self-extracting archive

I could maintain a word list, but feel this is rather brittle.
At this stage, I would be happy with a simple entropy check on first N bytes - ie, anything high entropy is "compressed".
Wondering if there may be a more straight-forward solution.
btw, I'm aware of this https://superuser.com/questions/307678/how-do-i-extract-files-from-an-msi-package - but I need to do this on linux not windows, and file names mean nothing for my use case so 7zip works as good as msiexec for my use case (and works for other archives too).

compression and archive are not the same thing. You can have a compressed archive (like file.tar.xz) or an archive which each or some member compressed (like in most zip files) or uncompressed archives (like .tar, .a...) or zip files with uncompressed members.

libarchive's bsdtar will extract a wide range of archive formats (compressed or not), likely a lot more than 7zip.

binwalk might be useful to you as it can recursively extract information embedded in arbitrary files.

See also unar for some Microsoft .exe files.

See also Why is looping over find's output bad practice?

Yes, I'm aware compressed and archive are different. In my case I want to decompress all the things and see what pops out. You raise a good point though that my entropy check won't catch uncompressed archives. So I'm thinking I will just try unpack everything.

Good reminder about bsdtar. If it can do msi package then I will use that. Last time I used it I was unzipping a gzip (or maybe deflate - can't recall) file and streaming to stdout to get one small file at start out. All other tools decompressed the entire zip as the toc is at the end or some such. bsdtar was the only tool I could find which could identify files without the toc and stop early.

I'll look at unar. I was hoping to reduce conditional logic and just take a best effort approach using a single tool. So a tool that can unpack the most popular windows packages is ideal. But I may have to use more tools if I find some files get missed.

I'll adjust the code with my most up-to-date version tomorrow. I'll fix the hairy usage of find too. Thanks for pointing it out.

Ok, so I guess this doesn't exactly answer the question.
But it turns out the slowness was due to my original script processing each file one at a time. I found running in parallel was taking only ~30 seconds vs 10 minutes+ on a ~100MB self-extracting EXE.
The trade-off is of course forking ~1000 processes at a time.
Here is my updated script. It attempts to decompress all extracted files blindly. I've also corrected the hairy looping over find output:
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

root="$1"
file="$2"
level="${3:-0}"

SELF=/home/wineuser/bin/unpack

out="$root/${level}-${file}"

# NOTE: maybe want 7z -u to avoid overwriting distinct files that have same name
7z x "$file" -o"$out" -y || exit
script="$(cat <<EOF
for f do "$SELF" "$root" "\$f" "$((level+1))" & done
wait
EOF
)"
find "$out" -type f -exec bash -c "$script" "find-bash-$level-$file" {} +

Invoke the script like this:
/home/wineuser/bin/unpack output-dir installer.msi

I did investigate using an entropy check to check for compression - but I decided against using it as it a) had negligible performance improvement compared to running in parallel b) would miss uncompressed archives as pointed out in the comments.
In case it is of use to anyone, here is the entropy test:
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

#
# Actually, returning success unconditionally is faster
# when running in parallel, but spawns 1000s more processes
FILE="$1"
THRESHOLD="6" # conservative, could be 6.5 or 7 to reduce number of processes by about 1000
# apt install ent bc # on debian
ENTROPY=$(ent -t "$FILE" | cut -d, -f3 | tail -n +2)
[ "$(echo "$ENTROPY > $THRESHOLD" | bc -l)" = "1" ]


Please note, this works on simple msi and self-extracting exe only. It won't necessarily unpack archives embedded at arbitrary locations in a binary blob or if they're encoded in some way. It literally relies on whether 7z can detect an archive and unpack it.
